# How to sort rows taken from sqlite based on one column where date is stored?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a two dimensional sqlite db. In one of the columns there is a date stored in the following format `dd/MM/yyyy`. I get the data as two dimensional String array. How could I sort the rows according on the columns that contains the date?

I have tried the following code, but it gives incorrect output.

```
DaysDatabase info = new DaysDatabase(ourContext);
info.open();
mDays = info.getUntil();
info.close();

//this sorting is given wrong output
Arrays.sort(mDays, new Comparator<String[]>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(final String[] entry1, final String[] entry2) {
        final String time1 = entry1[3];
        final String time2 = entry2[3];
        return time1.compareTo(time2);
    }
});
```

Comment: `a date stored in the following format dd/MM/yyyy` is in the _wrong format_. You should store dates as valid [Time Strings](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: I didn't know that. Thank you) Now it works

Comment: Glad to know that.